# SciPy integrate.ode with large numbers

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve an ODE using SciPy's integrate.ode, but it fails. My suspicion is that it has something to do with the magnitude of the grid involved, so I tried the following two tests:

```
from scipy.integrate import ode

def bla(t,x):
    return 0
M0=1
t0,y0 = 0.5*M0,0.5*M0
r = ode(bla).set_integrator('dopri5')
r.set_initial_value(y0,t0)
t1 = M0
dt =0.01*M0
bli = np.array([])
while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
    bli = np.append(bli,r.y)
```

the array `bli` contains 50 elements with value `0.5` as it should be.

```
from scipy.integrate import ode

def bla(t,x):
    return 0
M0=1e13
t0,y0 = 0.5*M0,0.5*M0
r = ode(bla).set_integrator('dopri5')
r.set_initial_value(y0,t0)
t1 = M0
dt =0.01*M0
bli = np.array([])
while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
    bli = np.append(bli,r.y)
```

The array `bli` in this case contains a single element with value `5e12`, and `r.successful() = False`, as it shouldn't be.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you insert a `print t,x` statement in `bla` you can observe that as part of the initialization the solver performs an integration step with a hard-coded step size `h=1e-5` to get the optimal step size for the first "real" step. The second value evaluated is at offset `0.1*h=1e-6`. With `t=5e12` there is no difference between `t` and `t+0.1*h` or `t+h` in floating point numbers. That is why you get the error.

Short of changing the code of the `ode` class or using a different version or package that handles the initialization somewhat more dynamically, you can not solve this problem.

The general advice is that when using general solver packages to rescale the problem so that the state vector and the step sizes that the solver sees are in an appreciable range, somewhere between `1e-3` and `1e6`. You can do this by on the theoretical side by choosing appropriate units or by doing a rescaling in the ODE function when translating the state vector into model variables and back.